# Does it make sense to support several qwt revisions?

Tags: qt, qwt

does it make sense to support many revisions of qwt in codebase - and if yes, which revisions should I support?
The original code is already cluttered with
preprocessor magic like

*#if QWT_VERSION == 0x050000*

Long explain:
Years ago I adopted a small open-source project, put it on github and patched it to make it compilable on Ubuntu 8.04.
Recently I tried to add Travis-CI to the project when I realized it does not compile on my current Ubuntu due to QWT changes. So I kicked the code (mostly initilizer issues) and made it compile. 
On Travis-CI I still get compile errors due to wrong qwt version. Original code needed QWT5. Without deeper dive it seems there has been changes even between 6.0 and 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some changes between 6.0 and 6.1 - QwtLegend for example.

Qwt 6.0.0 was released 2011-04-15. Support for Qwt 5 isn't necessary unless you have serious reasons. Qwt 6.1 was released 2013-05-30 so it should not be problem to install it on current distributions from official or semi/official repos. Changes weren't too big so it should not be problem to maintain both versions.

Another problem is Qt4 vs. 5 - on some distros there is main version Qt5 but Qwt is compiled for Qt4 (ArchLinux for example).

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I just removed the qt3support flag from qmakefile. today I realized that there are also many qt4 / qt5 issues right now, e.g. qCustomEvent has been removed between 4.0 and 4.8